# Proof by induction two variables inductive assumption

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing, induction

I want to prove a hypothesis (H) for all $(m,n)$ where $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ by induction. I know H holds for base cases
$(h,k)\in B := 0\times \mathbb{R} \cup \mathbb{R}  \times 0$.

In the induction step, could I assume H holds for
$$
(h,k)\in S:= B\; \cup ( \{1,...,m\}\times \{1,...,n\}\setminus (m,n) )
$$
for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ and then show that H also holds for $(m,n)?$ In particular here we assumed H holds for both $(m-1,n),(m,n-1)$ but we also know both $(0,1),(1,0)$ are base cases so it seems it may work.

Is this rigorous? or does it depend on the specific of the proof?

Comment: A standard approach is to prove by induction on $k$ that $H(m,n)$ holds whenever $m+n=k$.